# Override Adminhtml importexport dataflow Profile Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, importexport, dataflow

I'm trying to override ProfileController located in

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php

I created a new module to handle that as following :

> app/etc/modules/FifoBox_ProductApproval.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <FifoBox_ProductApproval>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </FifoBox_ProductApproval>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

> app/code/local/FifoBox/ProductApproval/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <FifoBox_ProductApproval>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </FifoBox_ProductApproval>
    </modules>
    <global> 
         ....
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <fifoBox_productapproval before="Mage_Adminhtml">FifoBox_ProductApproval_Adminhtml</fifoBox_productapproval>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

And My main class (controller) located in :

> app/code/local/FifoBox/ProductApproval/controllers/Adminhtml/System/Convert/ProfileController.php

```
<?php require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'System' . DS . 'Convert' . DS . 'ProfileController.php';

class FifoBox_ProductApproval_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController extends Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController {

    public function batchRunAction() {

        die('Overriden');
    }

} ?>
```

But Magento still call overriding (**Original**) method (i.e can't access my new class), even I tried to put the new controller file in 
***app/local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php*** to avoid any xml config error but I got the same result, I cleared catch checked all logs even Apache ones with nothing

The only way I got my new code work is to modify the core file itself

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Overriding controllers in `app/code/local` does not work, because controllers are not loaded with the Magento autoloader.

But I guess the reason that your controller is not used, is that there is a controller `Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_GuiController` that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController` and the actual route is `adminhtml/system_convert_gui/batchRun` and not `adminhtml/system_convert_profile/batchRun`.

Try to add a class `FifoBox_ProductApproval_Adminhtml_System_Convert_GuiController` and see if this is used.